# How to print out the same returned value of a Random.Randint() function

Tags: python

I would like some assistance in figuring out a way to print out the same number that was generated by a Random.randint() function. I first assigned the value to a variable, like so:

```
randomPersuade = random.randint(200,5000)
```

The problem is that now I have to print out the same value that was returned from this function twice in 2 different print statements

```
userDecide2=input("Since you decided to keep the box, I will offer you" ,randomPersuade, "for the box.\nYes to keep and No to collect the cash amount")
```

and

```
print("You decided to collect the cash amount of", randomPersuade, "Enjoy!")
```

How would I adjust it that I print out the same value twice, and later I would have to generate a few other sets of random integers and do the same thing, would I have to create another RandomPersuade(2,3,4,5 etc)? Won't the function generate a new value for the 2nd print statement? I would test this out myself but I would have to complete the rest of the code before I can do so, which will take a while. Any help that can be given will be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: The random function is called only when you call it. Printing a variable will not call the random function. For your `print` statements to work, replace `, randomPersuade, ` with `+ str(randomPersudae) +`.

Comment: @JohnAnderson Noted, thanks! :)

Comment: @JohnAnderson `print()` takes multiple arguments, and prints them all, so you don't need to concatenate them.

Comment: @Lofi Did you try your code? It should have printed the same number both times.

Comment: @Barmar I just did and it printed the same value over again, which is a success! Turns out I just had to use Anderson's suggestions for my code to run, thanks :)

Comment: Did you think that whenever you use a variable it gets replaced with the expression you assigned to it? Variables simply hold values, they're not aliases for expressions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have already assigned a value for the variable `randomPersuade = random.randint(200,5000)` its value won't change unless you do `randomPersuade = random.randint(200,5000)` again.

Till then, the value for the variable remains unchanged, and you can use it multiple times without its value being changed